# Problem with a dark image on a light background in the button

Tags: android, android-layout

What could be wrong with the second solution?

The first button works fine.

In the second button, I prepared a dark image and gave a light background.

Everything is done as in the first case, only inverted colors

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/menuBtnOnStart"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_menu_btn_white"
    android:src="@drawable/menu_btn_on_start" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/menuBtnOnOptions"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_menu_btn_black"
    android:src="@drawable/menu_btn_on_options" />

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Can you add the drawable files?

Comment: Yes, I've already found a solution. Change background and src and MUST add `android: scaleType="fitXY"`

Comment: Glad you solved it, I would probably close the question as I doubt it will help anyone else in the future.